# HTTP 503 service unavailable after migrating IIS from 7.5 to 8.5 with sapnco.dll

Tags: iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5, sap-dotnet-connector

How are you guys,
I have application that consumes a function from a SAP system via RFC protocol using `sapnco.dll`.

pool is configured as follows:

[image]

Note : Version IIS and OS is

[image]

now I want to pass this application to a new version of IIS / OS with the same configuration:

[image]

getting the following error:

[image]

so / IIS versions :

[image]

Checking the event viewer I have this message:

[image]

Please, if you have any kind of query or comment, I will answer it as soon as possible, Thank you!

Comment: How did you pass the application from IIS7.5 to IIS8.5? Please check event viewer to get some error message. 503 means application crashed and service unavailable, so you need to get error message about application pool in event viewer.

Comment: @BruceZhang The server with IIS 7.5 is PRD, the server with IIS 8.5 was also 7.5 and DEV / QAS server but an update process was made in the future PRD will also go through this update process. about event viewer messages i just updated the question.

Comment: Run IIS manager as administrator and check the application pool. Try to start it and check if the issue still exists.